# Function in Mixins Vuejs not found

Tags: vuejs2, mixins

Hello I have a component:

```
<template>
 <upload-btn 
   color="black" 
   title="Carica foto" 
   :fileChangedCallback="fileChange" />
</template>
<script>
import  fileUploadMixin from './../mixins/fileUploadMixin';
export default {
  name: 'compoment',
  mixins: [fileUploadMixin],
  components:{
    'upload-btn': UploadButton
  },
  data(){..},
  methods: {
    fileChange(file){
      this.fileChanged(file);
    }
   }
</script>
```

And then my Mixin:

```
export default {
  data () {

  },
  methods: {
    fileChanged(file){
      if(file){
        this.itemImage = file;
        this.previewImage = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is it return this error like the mixins not is included, but actually is imported.

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1878 TypeError: this.fileChanged is not a
>   function

I have tried also change my mixin with:

```
methods: {
    fileChanged: function(file){}
}
```

but it doesn't work.

What i'm wrong?

Comment: Syntactc Seems correct, my doubt is in import statement. Can you make sure if it's resolving mixin ?

Comment: actually yes, I'm using vue-cli-serve, if mixin was not resolved it return error on compiling.
I try to change extension of mixin, I have put .vue and putting .js seems return different error!

Comment: yes the problem was I'm wrong the extension of my class.
thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For others developers.

I'have solved.

The problem was that my Mixins file extension was wrong.

I have put **Mixin.vue** instead of **Mixin.js**, thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the data block from your mixin, or returning an empty object from it.

Comment: This is not necessary. From my understanding these data blocks are merged

Answer (score 0):

The Mixin should be computed:

```
export default {
    data () {},
    computed: {
         fileChanged(file){
              if(file){
                   this.itemImage = file;
                   this.previewImage  = URL.createObjectURL(file);
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: return this error: Property or method "fileChanged" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive